# Rails logic if an association has a certain attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a User model with the following associations:

```
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
```

The Organization model has a boolean `approved` attribute.

**I would like to change something in the view if the user has an organization that has been approved.**

I've hunted around and am fairly new to rails, so I could use some advice on how to best query for this adjust the view accordingly.

Comment: you can use model scope

Comment: Would you mind giving a rails rookie a little more detail?

Comment: yeah sure. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a scope in `organization` model, `scope :approved, -> {where("approved = ?", true)` and then you can query approved organization this way:
`user.organizations.approved`

for more detail about scope you can check this [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)

Comment: I've added the scope, and added <% if @user.organizations.approved %><h1>Approved!</h1><% end %> to the user#show view. When I load that view, I see an uninitialized constant User::Organizations NameError. Any recommendations?

Comment: Well, `@user.organizations.approved` will give you a list of all approved organizations, but looking at your code it seems like what you need is  `if @user.organizations.approved?` . `approved?` method is readily available for your boolean type column `approved`.

Comment: Good catch, but I'm still seeing the uninitialized constant error.

Comment: Can you show your associations in `organization` and `membership` models as well?

Comment: may be `@user.organizations` return multiple organizations relation object so you can not directly check `approved?` on it

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. `@user.organizations.each do |org| if org.approved?....`

Comment: ```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  scope :approved, -> {where("approved = ?", true)}
end
```

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organizations
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or what but in `belongs_to` the model name should be singular. Correct way: `class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :organization belongs_to :user end`

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Also, the if statement that ended up working was this: `if @user.organizations.approved.exists?`